# Will catch statement be executed if try statement is running fine?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch, catch-block

I have written some code in try statement and during debugging,the code is working fine.
But after try statement, control is moving to catch statement and it is throwing Null Pointer Exception. Here is the code:-
[image]

Comment: Please post your code, not images of your code.

Comment: Recompile your code or clean it.

Comment: Take a look at your exception StackTrace, it should tell you which line throws the exception.

Comment: What does test.log do? Are you able to see the text "Clicking on sing in link" in logs? If not, then this might be the issue. test variable might be null.

Comment: Keep in mind that in debug mode, if you stop at a line, that line has not yet been executed. So if you get to `test.log(...` and jump into the catch when you step forward, that line's the big, bad exceptionthrower.

Comment: if `test` is `null` you will cause NPEs in both `try` and `catch`.

Answer (score 1):

The statements in the catch braces will be executed only if the statments in the try braces did throw an Exception.

Here, I think your `test` var is null, that's why you have that nullpointer.